# "Bottle" conditioning in a growler?

Tags: bottling, bottle-conditioning, growlers

I'm a week or so away from bottling and I was curious: I have a 2 L growler from a local brewery with one of those EZ-Cap type lids, will it be a good enough vessel to bottle condition?

Not having to fill an extra ~5 12 oz bottles sounds pretty good to me!

Edit: Specifically it is this growler.

[image: Stone Brewery 2L growler]